# Using Cypress and Vue.js, how can I find and select an element in a v-select dropdown?

Tags: vue.js, automated-tests, cypress, v-select

This is my code:

```xml
<v-select
      label="label"
      v-model="ccRcode"
      ref="ccRcode"
      :items="getData"
      item-text="descWithCode"
      item-value="code"
      value="{ ccRcode }"
      data-test='test'
></v-select>
```

Comment: Perhaps this [Using cypress with vuetify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610949/using-cypress-with-vuetify) helps? It pertains to Vuetify autocomplete, but involves selecting. Try something similar, if it doesn't work post the code you tried above and someone will work through it.

Comment: Have you tried this `cy.get("[data-test=test]").select("valueNameGoesHere");`?

Answer (score 20):

Assuming the item you want to select has the text "My Option", you can do:

```js
cy.get("[data-test=test]").parent().click()
cy.get(".v-menu__content").contains("My Option").click()
```

The first line opens the dropdown, and the second selects the item.

Comment: I have a problem with this, when I have a v-select right after the first v-select

Comment: @farahm you can probably target the right `v-select` with a more specific selector.

Comment: One note - this will fail in one specific scenario: if you invoke it from inside a `within()` block. To get past this, you can use `Cypress.$()` (see https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6666)

Comment: Also, this will fail if you have too many items on the select, since Vuetify only renders the visible ones.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
cy.get('[data-test=test]').type('valueNameGoesHere{enter}', {force: true})
```

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue with the respective the component. The fix we found is the following:

`cy.get('#selectID').click().trigger('mousedown'); // this makes sure the select will stay open`

2 options here, depends on if you have a wrapper for the options:
`cy.get('#selectOptionsWrapper').contains('yourOption').click();`

If you don't have a wrapper then just use contains:

`cy.contains('yourOption').click();`

Hope this will help others.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I needed a slight modification of [@benoit-blanchon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62993753/21301816)'s solution: `.v-list-item__content` instead of `.v-menu__content`:

```
cy.get('#my-select-identifier').parent().click()
cy.get(".v-list-item__content").contains("My Option").click()
```

Note: The last line of the solution by [@robert-pop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75533916/21301816) is a bit dangerous, since it performs a full page search, that can lead to problems if "My Option" appears somewhere else on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful if you are using **Vuetify**.

`v-select` with *normal* dropdown:

```js
cy.get('[data-test="test"]').click(); 
cy.get('.v-list-item').contains('option').click();
```

`v-select` with *checkboxes* in the dropdown:

```js
cy.get('[data-test="test"]').click(); 
cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').first().check(); // check the first option
```

Use `cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').check()` if you want to check all the options.